# psycopg2 module syntax error at or near "/"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to import a csv file into PostgreSQL through psycopg2. However, the csv file column name contains special characters. I can create a table through psycopg2 with these lines of code.

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE crimnalRate(CrimeDate DATE, 
                                        CrimeTime TIME,
                                        CrimeCode TEXT,
                                        Location TEXT,
                                        Description TEXT,
                                        "Inside/Outside" TEXT,
                                        Weapon Text,
                                        Post INT,
                                        District TEXT,
                                        Neighborhood TEXT,
                                        Longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
                                        Latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
                                        "Location 1" TEXT,
                                        Premise TEXT,
                                        vri_name1 TEXT,
                                        "Total Incidents" INT)''')
```

When I want to use **copy_from** function to import csv file with these lines of code.

```
df=open('BD1.csv','r')
cursor.copy_from(df,"crimnalRate", columns=('CrimeDate',
                                        'CrimeTime',
                                        'CrimeCode',
                                        'Location',
                                        'Description',
                                        'Inside/Outside',
                                        'Weapon',
                                        'Post',
                                        'District',
                                        'Neighborhood',
                                        'Longitude',
                                        'Latitude',
                                        'Location 1',
                                        'Premise',
                                        'vri_name1',
                                        'Total Incidents'),sep=",")
```

And it always return error **psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "/"**

I tried using back slash before the special character or put the special column name into double quote, but it still return the same error message.
How do I fix this error? Could anyone give me some advise? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to double quote column names containing special characters, like: `"'Inside/Outside'", "'Total Incidents'"` ... ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. Actually it is the other way around. From docs [Copy From](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from): 
"Note:the name of the table is not quoted: if the table name contains uppercase letters or special characters it must be quoted with double quotes:
cur.copy_from(f, ' "TABLE" ')". I added space added between ' and " for illustration purposes. In actual code there is no space.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import io, sys, psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='sweden')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t("x/y" INTEGER)')
f = io.StringIO('4711')
c.copy_from(f, 't', columns=['"x/y"'])
c.execute('SELECT * FROM t')
print(list(c))
```

I.e, include explicit double quotes for the "funny" column name. Imho, it's a bit ugly that you have to do this, but then again, the docs explicitly say that it's required for the table name, so it makes sense that the columns work the same way.